# Computing an average from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am sorry for a verlo long question, just trying to explain in details. My formatting is not very good, sorry for that as well. I had a PHP/ MySQL App that essentially was not truly relational as I had one large table for all student scores. Among other things, I was able to calculate the average score for each subject, such that the average appeared alongside a student's score. Now I have since split the table up, to have a number of tables which I am successfully querying and creating School Report Cards as before. The hardship is that I can no longer calculate the avaerages for any subject.

Since I had one table with 5 subjects and each of the subjects had 2 tests, I queried for data and calculated the average as follows:

The one table (Columns):

```
id date name exam_no term term year eng_mid eng_end mat_mid mat_end phy_mid phy_end bio_mid bio_end che_mid che_end
```

The one query:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM pupils_records2 
 WHERE grade='$grade' && class='$class' && year =  '$year' && term ='$term'";
 $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
//English
$eng_pupils1{$row['fname']} = $row['eng_mid'];
$eng_pupils2{$row['fname']} = $row['eng_end'];
$mid=(array_values($eng_pupils1));
$end=(array_values($eng_pupils2));

$add = function($a, $b) { return $a + $b;};

$eng_total = array_map($add, $mid, $end);

foreach ($eng_total as $key => $value){
 if ($value==''){
 unset ($eng_total[$key]);
 }
}

$eng_no=count($eng_total);

$eng_ave=array_sum($eng_total)/$eng_no;
$eng_ave=round($eng_ave,1);
```

//Mathematics

```
$mat_pupils1{$row['fname']} = $row['mat_mid'];
$mat_pupils2{$row['fname']} = $row['mat_end'];
$mid=(array_values($mat_pupils1));
$end=(array_values($mat_pupils2));
$add = function($a, $b) { return $a + $b;};
$mat_total = array_map($add, $mid, $end);
foreach ($mat_total as $key => $value){
 if ($value==''){
 unset ($mat_total[$key]);
 }
}
print_r($mat_total);
$mat_no=count($mat_total);
echo '<br />';
print_r($mat_no);
$mat_ave=array_sum($mat_total)/$mat_no;
$mat_ave=round($mat_ave,1);
 }
}
```

//Biology
etc

I split the table into separate tables and have names in a separate table, not needed for calculating avaerages, so I will not show it here. Each subject table tajkes the following form:

```
id date exam_no term year grade class test*
```

*Test would be eng_mid or eng_end or mat_mid etc.

Because I had only one query which returned 10 rows (5 subjects each with two tests: e.g. eng_mid (English Mit exam), eng_end (english end of term test), I was able to capture all rows in one call and pack each subject into an array, and then work out the class average, with the help of array_map. It may not be elegant, but it worked very well.  Now, I have each test in it's own table.

I was trying to write a joint so as to get a signle resultset but the query fails. The columns as like:

I know that the database design is not anything to be proud off, but coming from a huge single table, this is a massive step (worthy a pat on the shoulder).

What I wish to do is to be able to query all my data and calculate class averages (about 30 students in each class). I tried to use separate queries but I ran into a wall, in that previously I would use the WHILE conditional as shown after the query for it to pull all rows and create an array  from which I could get desired results. Now several queries just makes me confused as to how I can archieve the same results since a join is not working. Also I am having a separate $row variable, and that throws me further off balance!

**Is it even possible to do averages as I did on my infamous one table (from the dark side) or is my table design so messed up, what I want just isn't humanly possible?**

Please any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You cannot use string interpolation or concatenation to introduce user data in your queries. `mysqli` has the [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method to do this for you and it is extremely important that you use that facility.

Comment: This is sample code, that is closer to what I actually have, it's not exact ans is only meant to highlight a problem. That said, your suggestion is valued.

Comment: It's important to be sure code like that **never** enters production, and quite often the sample code people paste here is all too similar to what they do in the course of their work. I'd argue code like that should never be written in the first place, even if you're "just testing something", since test code does have a way of being committed and rolled out by accident, and the cost of an accident like this could be staggering.

Comment: @tadman Yeah, what if this guy's homework gets hacked? This could cause a staggering accident, even the NSA would get on it.

Comment: @tadman, please let others help. Everyone strats from somewhere. You must be really great to not have written bad code.

Comment: Yo realise this is a learning app. Everyone starts from somewhere,. You have to make mistakes in order to get it right. While, I appreciate your concern, my problem is you are going too far, especially you are not doiung anything to help ensure I write good SQL. I am reading SQL, MySQL and PHP. With the help of a great many people, I will become good, or just better as I am willing to learn and am doing so by actually tingering with code. To say such code should not be written at all, is like saying Windows 3 must not have been created at all, Microsoft should have started with Windows 8!!!

Comment: @DanyCaissy The PHP community is so staggeringly ignorant of proper escaping practices even to the point of being hostile to them. Don't blow this off as being an academic concern. It is not an unreasonable thing to say "If you're going to learn this, learn how to do it correctly." and correctly in this case is often three more lines of code.

Comment: @Bululu I'm saying don't leave a loaded gun on the table with the safety off when there's children around. When something like this bites you in the ass, it will bite hard. There's no way to undo getting hacked and having your database posted somewhere.

Comment: @tadman, Dude, relax, you will have a heart attack! Trust me, this is not going online, so It wont be hacked. You obviosly have bigger problems than this, actually Microsoft may need your help as they wrote very bad code, such that a Google Researcher went public instead of alerting them, he was as pissed about them as you are abnout me, so help them, I am fine. Your suggestion is valued, though!

Comment: It is amazing how people in the PHP community will whine, complain, and make all kinds of excuses when implementing this correctly and bug-free is literally two more lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`union`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html). It would be something like

```
select grade, test from math
union all
select grade, test from english
union all
....
```

Also, in my opinion, better design would be to have table `exams` something like that (warning, pseudo-DML):

```
id int primary key,
student_id int foreign key students
subject_id int foreign key subjects
exam_type_id int foreign key exam_types 
grade int(????)
```

- `exam_types` table would be just midterm and final, but you'll be able to easily support more types in future, if required.
- `subjects` table will store all kinds of subjects you have (at this time there will be only five of them: math, eng, phy, etc.

The averaging query would be as simple as (yes, you can actually do [aggregation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) in the query itself)

```
select student_id, avg(grade)
from exams
group by student_id
```

Comment: Thanks very much @J0HN, let me try it and see what I get

Comment: I still have some milage before I can work it out in such a way that I have the subjects on their own, and then have the types of test seperately so that an increase in tests will scale well. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction